# Spring boot cannot connect with Elasticsearch image on server

Tags: spring-boot, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, dockerfile

i have spring boot project and using Elasticsearch inside it
i am run Elasticsearch by docker image

i think backend code cannot connect with Elasticsearch

but when run production in server i have following error

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Error while for indexExists request: org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.get.GetIndexRequest@446b74b9
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.indexExists(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:842)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.createIndexIfNotCreated(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:1219)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.createIndex(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:251)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository.createIndex(AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java:99)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository.<init>(AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java:89)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.<init>(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:39)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:204)
    ... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Timeout connecting to [/206.189.178.228:9200]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$SyncResponseListener.get(RestClient.java:959)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:233)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1764)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1734)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.exists(IndicesClient.java:1109)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.indexExists(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:840)
    ... 79 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Timeout connecting to [/206.189.178.228:9200]
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.RouteSpecificPool.timeout(RouteSpecificPool.java:169)
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool.requestTimeout(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:632)
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool$InternalSessionRequestCallback.timeout(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:898)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.SessionRequestImpl.timeout(SessionRequestImpl.java:198)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processTimeouts(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:213)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:158)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:351)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:221)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**this is elasticSearch.yml**

```
   version: '2'
services:
  searchservice-elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.1.0
    # volumes:
    #     - ~/volumes/jhipster/SearchService/elasticsearch/:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    environment:
      - 'ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m'
      - 'discovery.type=single-node'
```

**this is searchService.yml**

```
            version: '2'
    services:
      food-search-service:

    image: altshiftcreative/food-app-search-service:v1.6
    environment:
      # - _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512m -Xms256m
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,swagger
      - MANAGEMENT_METRICS_EXPORT_PROMETHEUS_ENABLED=false
      - EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE_URL_DEFAULTZONE=http://admin:$${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/eureka
      - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI=http://admin:$${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/config
      - SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_PROVIDER_OIDC_ISSUER_URI=https://shopbia.shop/auth/realms/jhipster
      - SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_OIDC_CLIENT_ID=internal
      - SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_OIDC_CLIENT_SECRET=internal
      - SPRING_DATA_JEST_URI=http://206.189.178.228:9200
      - SPRING_ELASTICSEARCH_REST_URIS=http://0.0.0.0:9200
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=false
      - elasticsearch.host=http://206.189.178.228:9200
      # - JHIPSTER_SLEEP=30 # gives time for other services to boot before the application
      - KAFKA_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS=kafka:9092
    ports:
      - 8088:8088
    networks:
      - food_default
networks:
  food_default:
    external: true
```

**and this is elastic search configuration inside my project**

```
public class ElasticsearchConfiguration extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {

@Override
@Bean
public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {

    final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration =
        ClientConfiguration
            .builder()
            .connectedTo("206.189.178.228:9200")
            .build();

    return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
}
```

**and this is application-prod.yml**

```
spring:
  data:
    jest:
      uri: http://206.189.178.228:9200
  elasticsearch:
    rest:
      uris: http://206.189.178.228:9200
```